# Can not find kubeconfig file

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access, kubernetes, configure

I am trying to access a remote kubernetes cluster with kubectl. In order to copy/paste cluster credentials in the kubeconfig file I executed "**~/.kube/config**" command but there is an error saying "**No such file or directory**".

Could anyone please tell me why i get this error? kubectl is perfectly working.

Answer (score 1):

`~/.kube/config` is not a command

You should copy the `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` file from one of your Kubernetes master node, to `~/.kube/config` on your host.

```
scp root@master1.example.lan:/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config
```

Then, you may use `kubectl` or `oc` - having installed them as well.